# Why are certain word related to deity dashed out?

Tags: discussion

I'm a passing visitor to mi yodeya so please excuse me if I'm being ignorant here, but I noticed that a few of the words referring to deity are not completed and simply 'dashed' out (I'm not stating them in whole in case for some reason it's due to respect).

[Converts to be treated as if they were born Jewish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60921/converts-to-be-treated-as-if-they-were-born-jewish?newreg=2d0d689c75604c1ba515fabbf9369b01)

This is the question that I saw, but there are multiple others (it appears to be all of them).  Can some explain the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Also dealt with at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1353 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32 and the various [main] questions linked to from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1828. None of those is exactly a duplicate of this question, but they may help clarify things for you, KronoS, in case no one answers below.

Comment: Re "I'm not stating them in whole in case for some reason it's due to respect": thank you for your consideration!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Different people handle this in different ways; some people don't mind writing a translation of a divine name in full, and others are careful to avoid doing so.  Each participant is free to follow his own practice; as with transliteration conventions or matters of style, we let all the variations stand and don't try to edit them.

The practice has its roots in the extreme care we take in treating divine names in Hebrew.  We don't write them frivolously and we take extra care in disposing of papers containing them.  (And even if *we're* writing online, we don't want to be the cause of somebody else printing it out and then not treating that paper appropriately.)  For more about this, see [this question on the main site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36675/472).

Comment: Is this due to the commandment of not taking His name in vain?

Comment: @KronoS Yes. [15]

Comment: Interesting.  As a Christian myself, I feel that sometimes we take His name a little too lightly.  While I refrain from statements like "Oh my ---!", I would've never thought to give respect even in writing and especially online publications.  The amount of respect shown for His name by the jewish faith is commendable.  Thank you.